# How to combine elements from a list with both strings and integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list

```
results = [[('Gizmo1', 1.0), 'Owner1'], [('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2'],[('Gizmo1', 4.0), 'Owner1'],[('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2']]
```

My Goal is to add the gizmos up matching the respecting owners.

```
 results = [[('Gizmo1', 5.0), 'Owner1'], [('Gizmo2', 8.0), 'Owner2']]
```

I have attempted to split the list into two smaller lists, create a dictionary

```
items_qty = [[('Gizmo1', 1.0)], [('Gizmo2', 4.0)],[('Gizmo1', 4.0)],[('Gizmo2', 4.0)]]

owner = [['Owner1'], ['Owner2'],['Owner1'],['Owner2']]

data = {}
for key, val in zip(owner, items_qty):
    data[key] = data.get(key, 0) + val
```

But this gives me an error of

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

How I get or save the information doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temporary `dict` to store intermediate results and then reconstruct `results` from that:

```py
results = [[('Gizmo1', 1.0), 'Owner1'], [('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2'],[('Gizmo1', 4.0), 'Owner1'],[('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2']]

temp = {}
for item,owner in results:
    if owner in temp:
        _,value = item
        prev = temp[owner]
        temp[owner] = prev[0],prev[1]+value
    else:
        temp[owner] = item
#print(temp)

results = [[value, key] for key,value in temp.items()]
print(results)
```

Output as requested

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    items_qty = [[('Gizmo1', 1.0)], [('Gizmo2', 4.0)],[('Gizmo1', 4.0)], [('Gizmo2', 4.0)]]

owner = [['Owner1'], ['Owner2'],['Owner1'],['Owner2']]

data = {}
for key, val in zip(owner, items_qty):
    print(key)
    giz, num = val[0]
    (_, newNum) = data.get(key[0], (giz, 0))
    newNum += num
    
    data[key[0]] = (giz, newNum)
```

The problem is that you are adding the number to the tuple, not to the value inside it.

Comment: Returns  (giz, num) = val
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: My bad, you had to add [0] to the key and value because it takes them as lists, already edited

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
results = [[('Gizmo1', 1.0), 'Owner1'], [('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2'], 
[('Gizmo1', 4.0), 'Owner1'],[('Gizmo2', 4.0), 'Owner2']]

data = {}
for element in results:
    gizmo_value = element[0][1]
    gizmo_name = element[0][0]
    owner = element[1]
    try:
        data[owner][gizmo_name] += gizmo_value
    except KeyError:
        data[owner]={ gizmo_name: gizmo_value }
```

With this logic you will get a dictionary with all the data just like you name it. It all depends on how you name things up.

Answer (score 0):

You kept a list of list of one tuple in your `items_qty` variable.
What you get in `val` is a tuple and `val[0]` is `"GuizmoX"` while `val[1]` is the value you try to add.